# Print sub-string having most repetitive characters set

Tags: java, algorithm

Eg 1: if I have numbers like 
1 2 3 4 1 3 4 5 6 1 4 5 6 2 1 2

it should print `1 2 3 4 1 3 4 5 6 1 4 5 6 2 1` because 1 comes 4 times

Eg 2: 2 3 4 2 2 1 3 4 5 6 7

it should print `2 3 4 2 2` because it has max occurrence

I know the basic approach where we have to find the max occurrence digit and after that we have to search the start and last index of that digit in input array and print it.

I want any other better approach if possible.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Implement it that way and then see if you have any performance problems.

Comment: I think your existing apporach is quite good already. If you have a working solution with that implemented I see no reason to change it. But also: Your description of the rules is incomplete. For example if we have "1 2 1 2" should it print "1 2 1" or "2 1 2"? Both digits appear twice and you haven't told us what the rule is in that case.

Comment: Add your value in key value pair and update the key value on each occurrence. You will get highest occurrence item respective their key.

Comment: @C-Otto please check my tag.. I am not asking for code. I just want to know the better algorithm, if possible.

Comment: Then SO is not the right place for you, I think.

Comment: I think you are not correct.. if this is place not for me then remove the "Algorithm" tag .. BRO.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For each character in the string maintain the count, and the index of its first and its last occurrence in a `Map<Character,FirstAndLast>` (see below)
- Once the map is complete, walk its values, and pick one with the highest `count`; pick a strategy for resolving ties
- Take a substring between `first` and `last`, inclusive, for the value with the largest `count`.

Class `FirstAndLast` is a simple object representing a pair of integers:

```
class FirstAndLast {
    private int first, last, count;
    public FirstAndLast(int index) { first = last = index; count = 1;}
    public int getFirst() { return first; }
    public int getLast() { return last; }
    public int getCount() { return count; }
    public void setFirst(int index) { first = index; }
    public void setLast(int index) { last = index; }
    public void incrementCount() { count++; }
}
```